# how to convert the unicode to latin characters python

Tags: python, unicode

I want to convert the unicode to its latin character using python, I have a big text file having the tweets containing the unicode and all. I just want to replace 4 unicode like \u00f6, \u015f ,..
I just want how the tweet was actually tweeted.(original language).Here is the code which actually collects the tweets and saves into the text file.I have added"#!/usr/bin/python

## *** coding :ISO 8859-9_*_...."I get this error "Non-ASCII character '\xf6' in file turkey_code.py on line 21, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details"

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        try:
            dirty = open('turkeyjson28.txt','a')
            encode = data.encode('ascii','ignore')
            dirty.write(encode)
            good = tweet.decode("utf-8") """
            better = good.decode("utf=8").replace(u"\u00f6", "ö")
            print better    
            dirty.write('\n')
            dirty.close()
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            #saveThis = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
            saveFile = open('turkey_clean28.txt','a')
            saveFile.write(better)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)
    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track = ["turkey"])
```

Comment: `.encode("latin1")`  may be what you are looking for ... but its hard to tell ... it would be better if you simplified your problem to just call `on_data` with a hardcoded string that doesnt work how you want ... using utf8 is more common though

Comment: thanks, but that didnt help

Answer (score 2):

The next function allow to convert string unicode to any encoding, for example:

```
>>> string = 'は | ő | ó | o'
>>> normalize(string, 'latin-1')
' | o | ó | o'

>>> normalize(string)
' | o | o | o'
```

The default encoding is "ascii".

Function code:

````py
from typing import Optional
import html
import unicodedata

def normalize(value: str, encoding: Optional[str] = None) -> str:
    """
    Normalize characters not maintainable when encode. 
    The default encoding is "ascii".
    ```
    # は non-latin-1 and not normalizable
    # ő non-latin-1 char but normalizable
    # ó latin-1 char
    # o ascii char
    >>> string = 'は | ő | ó | o'
    >>> normalize(string, 'latin-1')
    ' | o | ó | o'

    >>> normalize(string)
    ' | o | o | o'


    ```
    """
    if encoding is None:
        # Normalize non-encoding characters.
        # 'は | ő | ó | o' input
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        # ' | o | o | o' returned string

    # 'は | ő | ó | o' input
    # Replace with backslashreplace non-encoding characters
    value = value.encode(encoding, 'backslashreplace').decode(encoding)
    # '\\u306f | \\u0151 | ó | o' funtion output

    # Replace with xmlcharrefreplace encoding-non-ascii characters
    # and reverce backslashreplace
    value = value.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode('unicode-escape')
    # 'は | ő | &#243; | o' funtion output

    # Normalize non-encoding characters.
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    # ' | o | &#243; | o' funtion output

    # Reverce xmlcharrefreplace
    #' | o | ó | o' retured string
    return html.unescape(value)
````

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
better = good.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u00f6", "ö")
```

change to

```
better = good.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u00f6", u"\u00f6".encode("utf8"))
```

or as the first line of your file you need

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

In general I would avoid using the coding solution and just replace it with the unicode character encoded how you want

I will often write a pair of helper functions to assist with this job

```
def decode(byte_str,encodings=["latin1","utf8","cp1252"]):
    if not isinstance(byte_str,str) and isinstance(byte_str,unicode):
       byte_str = encode(byte_str,encodings)
    for enc in encodings:
       try:
          return byte_str.decode(enc)
       except UnicodeDecodeError:
          continue

def encode(unicode_txt,encodings=["latin1","utf8","cp1252"]):
    if not isinstance(unicode_txt,unicode) and isinstance(unicode_txt,str):
       unicode_txt = decode(unicode_txt,encodings)
    for enc in encodings:
       try:
          return unicode_txt.encode(enc)
       except UnicodeDecodeError:
          continue

#then you can just do something like
decode(good).replace(u"\u00f6",decode(u"\u00f6",encodings=["utf8","latin1","ascii"]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a text file which has tweets with unicode, please help me on how to convert the tweets having unicode to turkish character.. I am new to python.. I am stuck...This is how my text file looks like"Turkey just got 46 hostages back from ISIS. How did that happen? http:\/\/t.co\/ELxQsArkWR http:\/\/t.co\/JEZF7uSvjY

 Fethullah G\u00fclen Hocaefendi\u2019den Ali Bula\u00e7\u2019a ge\u00e7mi\u015f olsun; \u0130dris Naim \u015eahin\u2019in annesi i\u00e7in taziye mesaj\u0131 http:\/\/t.co\/w2g2fADgbt
"